# Height of locked and unlocked columns not match in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo UI Grid witch one locked column, which has dynamic width and height. The Grid's container is resizing in CSS and I'm using `kendo.resize($("#grid"))` to fit Grid to it and everything works perfecly.

I have also a function triggered on window resize event which is adjusting the columns widths. Colums should occupy whole grid without showing bottom scrollbar if it's possible, but they also have minimum height. So I calculate the columns widths and set it to them, but when I have horizontal scrollbar in the unlocked colums container, the locked container do not match to it.

Normally locked columns shows white area in bottom if there is horizontal scrollbar but when I set the columns widths explicitly it woluld not.

I've reproduced my issue in this fiddle (it's a little simpler than I describe but idea is the same): http://dojo.telerik.com/ADaqe

When i open it grid should looks ok, but when you'll decrease width of right iframe and horizonal scrollbar will show - white area is not shown and just try to scroll the grid to the bottom and see what happen: [image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is private grid function `._adjustLockedHorizontalScrollBar()` which doing exacly what I needed:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    that._adjustLockedHorizontalScrollBar();
    ...
});
```

Here is updated fiddle: http://dojo.telerik.com/ADaqe/4

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use CSS to fix this, adding padding-bottom: 100% to the table inside the locked column worked for me.

```
.k-grid-content-locked {
   height: 100% !important; // overrides inline style

   table {
     padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
```

Tested in Chrome 75.0.3770.100, IE 11.76517134.0, Android 8 and iOS 12.2

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! `.k-grid-content-locked {    height: 100% !important; } ` was enough in my case. Adding padding broke my layout.

Comment: This breaks the layout when the grid scrolls vertically. The locked column becomes larger than the table.